# invalid escape sequence when open csv file in julia

Tags: julia

when open the CSV file in *julia* it give **"Invalid Escape Sequence"** error.[Invalid Escape Sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9hn0.png)

```
julia> using CSV

julia> wikiEVDraw = CSV.read("D:\Online_Courses\...\wikipediaEVDraw.csv")
ERROR: syntax: invalid escape sequence
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that Julia interprets `\O`, `\.` and `\w` in this example as an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence), but since neither of those is a valid escape sequence, that is why you get a syntax error with that error message, ie:

```
julia> path = "D:\Online_Courses\...\wikipediaEVDraw.csv"
ERROR: syntax: invalid escape sequence
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[32]:0
```

Escape `\` with `\\` because you want to interpret `\` as a literal backslash, not as the beginning of an escape sequence:

```
julia> path = "D:\\Online_Courses\\...\\wikipediaEVDraw.csv"
"D:\\Online_Courses\\...\\wikipediaEVDraw.csv"
```

And then this will work:

```
julia> wikiEVDraw = CSV.read("D:\\Online_Courses\\...\\wikipediaEVDraw.csv")
```

Or use `@raw_str` string macro to do it automatically:

```
julia> path = raw"D:\Online_Courses\...\wikipediaEVDraw.csv"
"D:\\Online_Courses\\...\\wikipediaEVDraw.csv"
```

So you can do:

```
julia> wikiEVDraw = CSV.read(raw"D:\Online_Courses\...\wikipediaEVDraw.csv")
```

Or you can also use forward slashes `/` for paths as in Linux or MacOS instead of the backslash `\` for windows specific paths inside strings:

```
julia> wikiEVDraw = CSV.read("D:/Online_Courses/.../wikipediaEVDraw.csv")
```