# Using "r" for escape sequence when file in Julia

Tags: string, julia

On the Python using *r* front of the file path, can deal with escape sequence such as :

```
   df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\datasets\42133.csv")
```

However on Julia, the below code returns, *MethodError: no method matching joinpath(::Regex)*

```
file_path = r"D:\datasets\42133.csv"
df = DataFrame(CSV.File(file_path))
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61947005/invalid-escape-sequence-when-open-csv-file-in-julia), and know that I can chage `\` to `\\` or `/`. But wondering that why Julia does not allowed to use `r"String"`? Also is there something like `r"String"` on Julia?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [`raw"..."`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.@raw_str) string.

```
julia> raw"D:\datasets\42133.csv"
"D:\\datasets\\42133.csv"
```

In Julia, [`r"..."`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.@r_str) strings create a Regex object.